# Error app crash and error network with react native

Tags: react-native, expo, crash

I have a react native project with expo, I was testing the app and I noticed that it started to fail in some things, when I called my api (which was already working well) it gave me this type of error **[TypeError: Network request failed]** and I decided to reload the app and I got this error.

```
ERROR  Your app just crashed. See the error below.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8208 byte allocation with 565368 free bytes and 552KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
 okio.Segment.<init>(Segment.kt:62)
 okio.SegmentPool.take(SegmentPool.kt:87)
 okio.Buffer.writableSegment$okio(Buffer.kt:1805)
 okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.kt:1624)
 okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.kt:183)
 okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$toRequestBody$2.writeTo(RequestBody.kt:152)
 com.facebook.react.modules.network.ProgressRequestBody.writeTo(ProgressRequestBody.java:52)
 com.facebook.flipper.plugins.network.FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.cloneBodyAndInvalidateRequest(FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.java:119)
 com.facebook.flipper.plugins.network.FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.intercept(FlipperOkhttpInterceptor.java:91)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpNetworkInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:22)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpAppInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:53)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpAppInterceptor.intercept(ExpoNetworkInspectOkHttpInterceptors.kt:53)
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
 okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

I read on other pages about this and it has to do with excessive rendering on the part of react or not clearing states correctly when a component is unmounted, I will try clearing states and using useCallback hook to memoize callback functions and avoid unnecessary re-renders.